# How to convert an Image instance to File instance in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, file-upload, flutter-image, flutter-http, flutter-file

I am using **VideoThumbanil** class to fetch an **Uint8List** image of a video like this:

```
final uint8List = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(video: videoFile.path,);
```

After doing so, i am converting the **Uint8LIST** to an **Image** using the following code:

```
Image image = Image.memory(uint8List);
```

What I want to do is to convert this *image* to a **File** class instance so that I can upload this image to my server. Code for uploading on server is:

```
void asyncFileUpload(File file) async {
  //create multipart request for POST or PATCH method
  var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse("127.0.0.1/upload"));
  //create multipart using filepath, string or bytes
  var pic = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("image", file.path);
  //add multipart to request
  request.files.add(pic);
  var response = await request.send();
  //Get the response from the server
  var responseData = await response.stream.toBytes();
  var responseString = String.fromCharCodes(responseData);
  print(responseString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the path to the temporary directory:

```
final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
```

After doing so, you can create a File in that temporary directory:

```
File fileToBeUploaded = await File('${tempDir.path}/image.png').create();
```

This way your file has a path and it's instance has been created. Now, you can write the file as:

```
fileToBeUploaded.writeAsBytesSync(uint8List);
```

Now, you can use *fileToBeUploaded* as File that is actually an image.

Complete code:

```
final uint8List = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(video: videoFile.path,);
final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
File fileToBeUploaded = await File('${tempDir.path}/image.png').create();
fileToBeUploaded.writeAsBytesSync(uint8List);
asyncFileUpload(fileToBeUploaded);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the uint8 list you can try

```
File fileTpSend = File.fromRawPath(Uint8List uint8List);
```

Comment: I have the uint8List but i don't have it's path, I'll need to store it somewhere to move forward.

Comment: You already have this uint8List as final variable.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code you need to import `'dart:io'` and user `fromRawPath` function from `File` class (check snippet below)

```
import 'dart:io';

final uint8List = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(video:videoFile.path);
final imageAsFile = File.fromRawPath(uint8List);
await asyncFileUpload(imageAsFile);
```

But this method doesn't work for Flutter WEB